# Deleting or adding a node in WPF MVVM Treeview

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am new to these stuffs. Hence I request for your help.I want to delete and add a node to a treeview in WPF MVVM. I have managed to create the treeview using :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354853/WPF-Organization-Chart-Hierarchy-MVVM-Application
but now I am not able to figure out how can I add/delete a node and then refresh the treeview. 
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a few moments to read through the various pages of the StackOverflow [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, please pay close attention to the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, as your question is of fairly low quality.

Answer (score 0):

That is the problem with copying other people's code and not bothering to find out how it works. In WPF, we manage *data* elements, not *UI elements*, so to add another item into any UI container control, we simply add a *data* item into whichever *data collection* that is data bound to the `ItemsSource` property of the container control. In your linked article, you can see the following:

### Tree View

> The DataContext of the TreeView is the OrgTreeViewModel. We set the TreeView's ItemsSource to the Root property of the OrgTreeViewModel, which is the top-most node in the hierarchy.

It therefore seems as though you have a collection property named `Root` in your `OrgTreeViewModel` view model class. So, all you need to do to add a new item into your `TreeView` is to add a new *data object* into your `Root` collection. If that tutorial is any good, then the UI will automatically update, showing the new item.